# dynamically created JSX elements with onAction={} attributes ,do not update state (THEY ARE BROKEN)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, es6-promise

Consider these two `setState` variables ,whose values change after a promise was successful (ex . ajax call)

```
const [ajax_response,getAjax_response] = useState("awaiting response"); //This one stores the ajax call response
const [showAjax,setShowAjax] = useState([]) //This one displays it
```

The promise is made using the `useEffect` hook which is called when specified (in this example in the first render)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(data => {
      //Here it stores the value in the first useState variable
      getAjax_response(data[0])

      //Here it loops throw the data and DYNAMICALLY CREATES some attributes based on the repsponse
      //In this example it just fetches a single number from the ajax call
      //And performs a loop until it reaches that (IRELEVANT)

      for (let i=0;i < data[0];i++) {
        let styled_data = <p onClick={() => console.log(ajax_response)}>{i}</p>;
        setShowAjax(prev => [...prev,styled_data])
      }
    })
  },[])
```

**Basically what happens** :

- The value returned from the promise is set to `ajax_response`, let's say that it was **CAT**
- the `showAjax` is set to a JSX element with a `onClick={}` Attribute

## The problem :

- If this was returned in our render

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => console.log(ajax_response)}>THE NORMAL BUTTON</button> //Button set manually
      {showAjax} //The JSX elements set dynamically
    </div>
  );
```

the `THE NORMAL BUTTON` would `console.log()` the `ajax_response` and get the correct answer

BUT THE DYNAMICALLY CREATED BUTTONS IN  `{showAjax}` console-logs only the **INITIAL STATE** of `ajax_response`

- so the output looks like this
- **Generated inside  **`{showAjax}`****

```
>>> awaiting response
```

- Normal Button

```
>>> CAT
```

## TL:DR

REACT ELEMENTS GENERATED DYNAMICALLY WITH ONCLICK ATTRIBUTES ARE BROKEN: THEY DO NOT SHOW UPDATED STATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let styled_data = <p onClick={() => console.log(ajax_response)}>{i}</p>;
setShowAjax(prev => [...prev,styled_data])
```

The issue is that you are storing react elements in state. This is usually a bad idea precisely because of the issue you're run into here: they will never rerender, and thus it's really easy to create bugs where you render stale data. The function in this `<p>` closes over the value of `ajax_response` that existed when the useEffect ran. Ie, it has "awaiting response" in its closure, and always will.

Instead, your state should be the data that you need to create the components, and then you'll create the components when rendering.

```
for (let i=0;i < data[0];i++) {
  // Modify this to store whatever data you need. 
  // Your example only used numbers, so i replicated that, but i expect your real code needs more.
  setShowAjax(prev => [...prev, i]); 
}

//...

return (
  <div className="App">
    <button onClick={() => console.log(ajax_response)}>THE NORMAL BUTTON</button>
    {showAjax.map(value => (
      <p onClick={() => console.log(ajax_response)}>{value}</p>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: map seemed to do the trick, just change the `{i}` with `value` in your .map function